# Мучаюсь с констрейнами не понимаю как это сделать

Tags: ios, swift

Поставьте в одну линию два лейбла: левый лейбл имеет отступ от левого края 8 pt, правый лейбл – 8 pt от правого. Между ними отступ тоже 8 pt. Сделайте так, чтобы в случае, если у обоих лейблов очень длинный текст, правый лейбл имел ширину 40 pt, а левый – все остальное пространство, при этом если в левом лейбле мало текста, то правый лейбл занимал всё доступное свободное пространство (при этом левый лейбл должен помещаться полностью).

Answer (score 1):

> Сделайте так, чтобы в случае, если у обоих лейблов очень длинный текст, правый лейбл имел ширину 40 pt, а левый – все остальное пространство

- установить у левого `Content Compression Resistance Priority` для горизонтали больше, чем у правого, чтобы указать приоритет сопротивления сжатию контента
- установить для правого констрейнт ширины >= 40

> при этом если в левом лейбле мало текста, то правый лейбл занимал всё
>   доступное свободное пространство (при этом левый лейбл должен
>   помещаться полностью)

- установить у левого `Content Hugging Priority` для горизонтали больше, чем у правого, чтобы указать приоритет подгонки размера под длину строки

Comment: Спасибо, уже решил